# android tv как получить событие

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как получить события нажатия на пульт телевизора (не D-pad) в android tv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так как-то:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

  if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Key down, code " + event.getKeyCode());
  } else if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Key up, code " + event.getKeyCode());
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: все заработало, спасибо за ответ)